# How to runCommand in specific directory?

Tags: haskell, process

I'm using `runCommand` from `System.Process` but I use

```
"cd " ++ path ++ " & " ++ args
```

And it's not good, even will not work if path is on different local drive in windows.

How can I handle current directory change for `runCommand` ?

Comment: Have you tried [setCurrentDirectory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:setCurrentDirectory) from `System.Directory`? Maybe if you set the working directory of the main program before using `runCommand`, the command would run in that directory.

Comment: I've changed my comment into an answer since it sounds like that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[setCurrentDirectory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3asetCurrentDirectory) from `System.Directory` changes the working directory of the main program.

If you do that before using `runCommand`, the command should use that directory too.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the source code of `runCommand` you can realize is just a thin wrapper for `createProcess` which is the one doing the real work. Here is an example taken from the [`createProcess` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v%3acreateProcess), which has been edited for convenience to address this question.

> ```
> (_, Just hout, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "/path/to/my/executable" [])
>                             { cwd = Just "/path/to/working-directory"
>                             , std_out = CreatePipe }
> ```

Comment: strange, I'm getting `createProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

Comment: The current directory for the executable is specified by `cwd`. I think you still have to pass the full path of your executable to `proc`, if it's not in your env variable `PATH`.

Comment: I've got executable in PATH but seems like this thing can't see it still:(

Comment: There is also the possibility of passing a custom `PATH` with the `env` argument of `createProcess`, but unless you have a specific need for this, I think it's just simpler to pass the full path to the executable.